# How to test the 'catch(e)' block in Mocha/Chai testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm currently trying to cover all the lines of code in this file, but I'm having trouble covering the lines within the `catch` block of my code. I have my test file written to cover everything else, how would I go about writing a unit-test to cover the `catch` block.

Comment: Did you remove the code on purpose? If not, please restore it, because the question is unanswerable as it is standing now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`proxyquire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to mock the `oAuthStarGate` function and throw an `Èrror` when called on some of your test cases:

`member-service.test.js`:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();

...

const memberService = proxyquire('./member-service', {
  './oAuthStarGate': (updatedState, event) => {
    throw new Error('Error thrown');
  },
});

...

assert.throws(memberService(...), Error, 'Error thrown');
```